# How to verify the nonce in WordPress if the request is from a link in the menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, sanitization

I have a plugin that has a submenu. For example: Dashboard, List of recent questions, Settings, Support.

The submenu is added using the add_submenu_page function.

```
add_submenu_page(
            'my-plugin',
            'Dashboard',
            'Dashboard',
            'manageoptions',
            'my-plugin&tab=dashboard',
            array(
                $this,
                'get_home_page',
            )
        );
```

Depending on the value of $_GET['tab'], I open the template I need.

```
$tab = ( isset( $_GET['tab'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['tab'] ) ) : '';

if ( 'dashbord' === $tab ) {
 require_once PLUGIN_DIR . 'templates/dashbord.php';
} elseif ( 'settings' === $tab ) {
 require_once PLUGIN_DIR . 'templates/settings.php';
}
```

When I check my code with a code sniffer with standard=WooCommerce-Core, it complains to me that "WARNING | Processing form data without nonce verification". On the line where I assign to the variable $tab the value of the array $_GET['tab'].

How to add wp nonce for menu link. And is there any common sense in this?

I tried using FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING for sanitizing. But the new version of php complains about it as a deprecated method.

Comment: In this instance, because you are only showing one tab or another, you aren’t making system changes based solely on the tab selection, you are guarding the tab option based on a finite and controlled selection, and you are relying on the WordPress `manageoptions` capability to show your menu in general, I don’t think a nonce is needed, and in fact overkill. So I would add a comment telling the tool to ignore this one.

Comment: WooCommerce has a lot of tabs and they suppress the warning. https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Awoocommerce%2Fwoocommerce%20%2F%2F%20phpcs%3Aignore%20WordPress.Security.NonceVerification.Missing&type=code it's fine if you know what you're doing.